# Problem uploading to App Store

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, app-store

I have downloaded the application loader to upload my app to the App Store. When uploading my app, I am getting the following error:

> App is not in valid location: it should be at top level of archive.

It would be a great help if you provide the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you uploading a .zip file or .app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app should be zipped and the archive name should not contain spaces.